# Get request object in a db model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way so that I can get access to request object, while saving a db object, without explicitly passing it e.g.

```
class RequestData(db.Model):
    ...
    def put(self):
        # autopopulate fields from current request
```

I just want a quick way to access request, instead of passing it thru so many layers of view/forms/etc

Comment: @Kugel, no it is GAE, we may run django there though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Google AppEngine uses CGI protocol, the request information is all there in the environment variables (See [CGI Environment Variables](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/env.html)).

You can regenerate the request object just like this:

```
req = google.appengine.ext.webapp.Request(dict(os.environ))
```

Comment: This appears to answer the question, what gives?

Comment: yes it is, I can get all the cookies which I wanted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any pre-built way of achieving this to the best of my knowledge, however writing such a piece of code should not be very hard.

If its GAE, the [self.request.arguments() method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_arguments) can be used to read the properties of the request object and thus should enable iteratively accessing values of all the request properties.

Comment: You would also want to build automated validations in this request-to-model interface.

Comment: i do not understand what you mean, can you give an example of how I can get request object in a db Model?

Answer (score 0):

views.py:

```
import threading
request_storage = threading.local()
def myview(request):
    request_storage.data = request
```

models.py:

```
class MyClass():
    def save():
        from views import request_storage
        request_storage.data.GET['myarg']
```

this will use request_storage instance from current thread

Comment: hmm. I didn't notice the tag. Was it there? No it isn't available there. In GAE I'd stick to Iamamac's version.